# How to use QAudioOutput in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

When I run QAudioOutput on Ubuntu Touch in confinement, It reports permission error.

Basically it is trying to create a directory in /run/user/*****/pulse which is rejected by the confinement.

How to use QAudioOutput, and what are other alternatives on Touch.

Answer (score 2):

So, I add 'audio' to the security policy group, and it is resolved.
This is the current apparmor file:

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "audio"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.1
}
```

I add line "audio" and solve the problem.
You can find app apparmor file in manifest.json.

Or you can use qtCreator, in "Publish: -> Security Policy Group, add audio. There you can see that it gives access to path: `/{,var/}run/user/*/pulse/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please just detail which file did you modify to solve your problem?

Comment: @SylvainPineau, more detailed solution is posted, thank you.